# Transfer data from excel to SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-transfer

I have some data in excel spreadsheet in below format:

[image]

and I want to transfer this to a SQL server table in below format:

[image]

Can you please help me out. Thank you,

Comment: So not the transfer is the question but the transformation?

Comment: Yes basically need to copy this data into a table. kind of both transferring with some transformation

Comment: I think you should split this into 2 questions, because asking an end-to-end solution from the community is not nice. And of course, show for both tasks where you are stuck.

Comment: Save As "Unicode text" or "Tab-Delimited Text". Open SSMS, right click on the database, Tasks -> Import File (if you are lucky, there may even be "Import Flat File"). Follow the steps. It's easy.

Comment: I will try out this option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not clear if this is a one-time import or part of a repetitive process.  So I will tackle the transformation step.  You can use CROSS APPLY to UNPIVOT your newly imported working table.  Please consider:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(ID int, col_1 int, col_2 int)

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES(10,111,555),
(11,333,777)


select t1.id,x.col,x.val 
from #tmp t1
cross apply(VALUES(1,t1.col_1),(2,t1.col_2)) x(col,val)
```